# Trouble Understanding the Benefit/Point of Server Actions in Next.js

Tags: next.js, server-action

I don't understand the importance of Server Actions in Next.js. For example take a look at the following code.

```
import prisma from '@/utils/db';

const PrismaExamplePage: React.FunctionComponent = async() => {
    await prisma.task.create({
        data: {
            name: 'Testing Something Out Right Now.'
        }
    });
    return (
        <h1>Prisma Example Page</h1>
    );
}

export default PrismaExamplePage;
```

Everything works. Then I see people do the same thing using Server Actions

```
import prisma from '@/utils/db';

const createTask = async() => {
    "use server";
    await prisma.task.create({
        data: {
            name: 'Testing Something Out Right Now.'
        }
    });
}

const PrismaExamplePage: React.FunctionComponent = async() => {
    await createTask();
    return (
        <h1>Prisma Example Page</h1>
    );
}

export default PrismaExamplePage;
```

What is the difference between me using Server Actions and not using Server Actions. I don't see the benefit or the point

I've heard some people argue that it makes the code readable but thats not a good answer. Because I can also make the code more readable and not use a server action.

```
import prisma from '@/utils/db';

const createTask = async() => {
    await prisma.task.create({
        data: {
            name: 'Testing Something Out Right Now.'
        }
    });
}
    
const PrismaExamplePage: React.FunctionComponent = async() => {
    await createTask();
    return (
        <h1>Prisma Example Page</h1>
    );
}
    
export default PrismaExamplePage;
```

Comment: In your example how would you make it so `createTask` is called based on a user interaction (like a form submission since it would be the case of such `createTask` example) without server actions? The idea behind them is so this logic is isolated in the server without having these actions being done in the client side. If your `createTask` required some sort of secret key, your risk having it exposed on the client.

Comment: Time has gone. Please select an answer or answer your question. This helps keep Stack Overflow tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some benefit of server actions :

- Reduced Client-side JavaScript: Next.js and React are moving in the
  direction of **minimizing the client side bundle** by offloading logic to
  the server. Next.js has enabled us to move a lot of code to the
  server, but we were still mostly building forms on the client. That
  changes with server actions!
- Enhanced user experience: With features like optimistic updates and
  progressive enhancement, developers can create applications that feel
  more responsive and seamless. Users no longer need to wait for server
  responses to see the effects of their actions, and **forms remain
  interactive even without JavaScript**, leading to a better overall user
  experience even before the client hydrates.
- Great developer experience: Server Actions make it seamless to
  **offload data updates** to the server, which would’ve required an API in
  the past. The APIs that Next.js and React provide make it really easy
  to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code renders on the server. If you want to `createTask()s` in client components (forms action, event handlers, ...) you are already done and can use your server action. Without, you would need an API.

> Server Actions are asynchronous functions that are **executed on the server**.

[Next.js App Router docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations)

One strong use case is Server Actions as form actions. Just see how comfortable one can use forms. I won't repeat the manual here but recommend reading the [forms examples](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#examples).

They are not limited to use with forms. Event handlers are another use case.

Well designed Server Actions integrate seamless with modern React and Next.js, another advantage over other solutions.

At the end of the day it's up to you, your knowledge, your tools you are comfortable with and the app you develop if you want to use Server Actions.